# CSS: Trying to rotate door without vertical translation

Tags: html, jquery, css, css-animations

I am fairly new to CSS, and I'm trying to learn how to rotate a door. The door rotates nicely when I click it, but it also looks like it came off the hinges (vertical translation)! Is there a way to correct it please?

Thank you for your input!

[image: door]
[image: doorFrame]

```js
d3.select("#chart")
  .append("image")
  .attr("xlink:href", "https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0sAO.jpg")
  .attr("x", 12)
  .attr("y", 30)
  .attr("width", "5.5em")
  .attr("height", "5.5em");

d3.select("#chart")
  .append("image")
  .attr("xlink:href", "https://i.stack.imgur.com/ox20F.jpg")
  .attr("id", "door")
  .attr("x", 27)
  .attr("y", 40)
  .attr("width", "58")
  .attr("height", "78");


$("#door").mousedown(function() {
  $("#door").addClass("doorOpened");
});
```

```css
.doorOpened {
  animation: spin 0.7s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(60deg);
    transform: skewY(20deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Revolving door</title>
</head>

<body>
  <svg id="chart"></svg>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Transforms have to be all on one line,  otherwise the last one is the only one used. However, for this case it would be good to learn about 3d transforms - they will do the 'skewing' for you and you can set the perspective - i.e. where the user is standing in relation to the door.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to replace your CSS with below:

```
.doorOpened {
    animation: spin 0.7s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-origin: 27px 50%;
}

@keyframes spin {
    0% {
        transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(0deg) skewY(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(50deg) skewY(20deg);
    }
}
```

[JSbin](https://jsbin.com/xibilapabi/edit?html,css,js,output)

Or Snippet :

```js
d3.select("#chart")
  .append("image")
  .attr("xlink:href", "https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0sAO.jpg")
  .attr("x", 12)
  .attr("y", 30)
  .attr("width", "5.5em")
  .attr("height", "5.5em");

d3.select("#chart")
  .append("image")
  .attr("xlink:href", "https://i.stack.imgur.com/ox20F.jpg")
  .attr("id", "door")
  .attr("x", 27)
  .attr("y", 40)
  .attr("width", "58")
  .attr("height", "78");


$("#door").mousedown(function() {
    $("#door").addClass("doorOpened") 
});
```

```css
.doorOpened {
  animation: spin 0.7s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-origin: 27px 50%;
}
@keyframes spin {
  0% {
      transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(0deg) skewY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
      transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(50deg) skewY(20deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Revolving door</title>
</head>

<body>
  <svg id="chart"></svg>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

```js
d3.select("#chart")
  .append("image")
  .attr("xlink:href", "https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0sAO.jpg")
  .attr("x", 12)
  .attr("y", 30)
  .attr("width", "5.5em")
  .attr("height", "5.5em");

d3.select("#chart")
  .append("image")
  .attr("xlink:href", "https://i.stack.imgur.com/ox20F.jpg")
  .attr("id", "door")
  .attr("x", 27)
  .attr("y", 40)
  .attr("width", "58")
  .attr("height", "78");


$("#door").mousedown(function() {
  $("#door").addClass("doorOpened");
});
```

```css
.doorOpened {
  animation: spin 0.7s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(18px) rotateY(80deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Revolving door</title>
</head>

<body>
  <svg id="chart"></svg>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer!

Answer (score 1):

First of all note that when applying multiple css transform properties you will have to write them in a single line. orelse the last transform property will override your previous properties.
eg) transform: scale() translate() rotate() skew()

For your problem, the skew will tilt the element to an applied degree.. and in this process the element is pushed down with percentage of the degree value.

so what you can do is translate the Y-axis of the element in negative value to set the element to its original posistion.

transform: skewY(20deg) translateY(-10px);

```js
d3.select("#chart")
  .append("image")
  .attr("xlink:href", "https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0sAO.jpg")
  .attr("x", 12)
  .attr("y", 30)
  .attr("width", "5.5em")
  .attr("height", "5.5em");

d3.select("#chart")
  .append("image")
  .attr("xlink:href", "https://i.stack.imgur.com/ox20F.jpg")
  .attr("id", "door")
  .attr("x", 27)
  .attr("y", 40)
  .attr("width", "58")
  .attr("height", "78");


$("#door").mousedown(function() {
  $("#door").addClass("doorOpened");
});
```

```css
.doorOpened {
  animation: spin 0.7s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: skewY(20deg) translateY(-10px);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Revolving door</title>
</head>

<body>
  <svg id="chart"></svg>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining me! You cleared several confusions I had.

Comment: I'm glad you found it useful.